# Is there a way to understand if Android App Update was installed by users?

Tags: android, google-play

I just published an update to my Android App on Android Market and Android market sent notification for the update which is fine. But I am trying to figure out if there is a way to know if the users installed the update that was published?

I do not see any details in Android Market Developer console.
These are users who were using the earlier version already not new users. Any insight would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can kinda see this if you're using Flurry.  If you're not using Flurry, it's really easy to set up (and it's free).  Flurry tags user sessions with the version of your app that's running and you can filter your stats on the website by version.  So, select the previous version, and you can see a chart of the number of users and sessions per day of that version.  This won't tell you exactly how many people upgraded, but you can get a feel for who didn't.

Comment: I love Flurry now...great way to track everything related to your App at one place. It's free!!

Comment: There's so much awesome in having mobile analytics.  Something I decided to do today is to release one of my apps on the Amazon Appstore and use different versions.  This way I can really see the usage differences (audience, geography, etc) relative to where the user got my app.

Answer (score 5):

You can track utilization with Google Analytics.

I'm doing this inside a changelist pop-up for the new version:

```
 if (!appPrefs.getAppVer().equals(getAppVerName())) {

    ...

    tracker.trackEvent("Home Screen", "Click", getAppVerName(), 1);
    appPrefs.saveAppVer(getAppVerName());
    appPrefs.saveAcceptedUsageAggrement(false);

 }
```

You can see that I set the AcceptedUsageAgreement to false so that gets displayed after an update too ;)

where getAppVerName() is ...

```
public String getAppVerName() {
    String text;
    try {
        text = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        text = "Version Not Found";
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough you've made me think about my own code a bit.  If I moved my tracker.trackEvent call into the onCreate of the main activity I'd get a running tally of how many uses each version was getting.  By making the "label" the app version name and setting the value to "1" you get a +1 on each version used each time the main activity screen is created ...  Might have to implement that for myself come to think of it.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to know if a user installed an update or force a user to install an update without adding special code to your app to force them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate Crashlytics into your app. This will give you a complete report of active users and crashes per day for each version you release.

[Tutorial to integrate Crashlytics to your app](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/overview.html)